# CollectionView inside ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I know there are already questions out there but I don't understand them or I just do not know what I am doing. So I am getting this error when I try to run my app

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:]
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier DateCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I do not understand why I am getting this or how to resolve it.

I have a cell class which I have registered

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!
}
```

And then here is my viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {    

    private let reuseIdentifier = "DateCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        initializeVars()
        //moreDateInfo()
    }
  
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return moreDateInfo()
    }
    
    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CVCell
        
        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.myCellLabel.text = String(startOfMonthDate)
        
        if (startOfMonthDate == numOfDaysInThisMonth) {
            startOfMonthDate = 1
        } else {
            startOfMonthDate++
        }
        
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor() // make cell more visible in our example project
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
    
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    
    
    // change background color back when user releases touch
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
```

Here is my storyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CVCell
```

does not actually register your CVCell class. To do that, you should use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in your `viewDidLoad`.  Alternatively, in your storyboard select the cell, and in property inspector on the right, enter "DataCell' under "reuse identifier".

Answer (score 1):

Your cell name is wrong its "DateCell"

And may be you need to register the nib class like below

self.collectionViewCategory.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SelectCategoriesCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

Comment: and may be at initially u need to register nib class :

Answer (score 1):

On my storyboards with prototype cells, it is not required to register the class. The storyboard takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I had a spelling error.....never forget those typos.

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "DateCell"
```

Should be "DataCell"